# When would store.findAll() return duplicate values?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm requesting Users from the server. There is only one user, and that's what comes over HTTP. However, when I loop over the rows returned from the `.findAll()` call, I see multiple values.

## My Route:

```
U.UsersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return {
            users: this.store.findAll('user')
        };
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model.users);
    }
});
```

## My Controller (abridged):

```
U.UsersIndexController = U.ApplicationArrayController.extend({
    _modelChanged: function() {
        this.get('model').then(_.bind(function(users) {
            _.each(users.get('content'), function(user) {

                // I should only see one name logged
                console.log(user.get('name'), user.get('id'));

            });
        }, this));
    }.observes('model', 'orgNameForId')
})
```

## Server response to GET `/users`

```
{
    "Results": [{
        "id": 16,
        "Name": "Chris"
    }]
}
```

When this runs, console shows 2 users, one that's `Chris 16` and the other that's `Chris null`.

## My questions

- Does the null ID mean something else in my code is creating the record?
- Should I just always filter out models without an ID?
- Help!

Comment: Did you initially create this user through your application? If so, when you create the user, it expects a call back from the server with an id. If not, I think it's left as null. Then, when you do your GET request, it's getting a new one while the old is still in memory. Also, ember-data expects the following format back from the server: `{ 'users' : [{ 'id': 16, 'Name": "Chris" }]}`. I'm surprised it worked as it is.

Comment: Yup, I totally had a local user that wasn't getting created properly. Good call. Also, I have an adapter that translates that response format. I forgot to mention that when I was simplifying my code for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a user in your application, it expects a success call back from the server with an id, which will automatically update for you if configured right. If not, it's left as null. When you do your GET request, it will add what the server sends it to ember-data, which will be another model that it won't recognize as the same one since the id won't match.

If you don't use it already, I'd check out the Ember Inspector Chrome plugin, which allows you to see routes, data, etc.

As mentioned in the comment, ember-data expects the following format, but you mentioned taking care of that in your adapter:

```
{ 'users' : [{ 
    'id': 16, 
    'Name": "Chris" }]
}
```

As for your last question, you shouldn't filter out models whose id is `null`. You should create your app so that there are no ids that are `null`.